# A Suite of Thirteen (Company #4)

Tags: pattern, knowledge, word-sequence

The following thirteen English words all share a certain property:

> ACE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN JACK QUEEN KING

However, there is a fourteenth word that belongs to this group, and it is not "Joker". What is that word?

Comment: Are there *only* fourteen in the group?

Comment: Usually there are only fourteen. I haven't personally heard of a case where there are more.

Comment: "Deuce" or "knave" seem like perfectly valid solutions to me (although I realise your comment is probably meant to be a hint).

Comment: Deuce is just two, and Knave is just jack. I'm looking for a word that's not equivalent to any of them.

Comment: This feels like a [trivia challenge rather than a puzzle](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2822/4551).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 14th word is:

> **KNIGHT** which is used in a [French Tarot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_tarot) deck of cards.  The Knight is ranked between the Jack and the Queen.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Well done.

Comment: @JoeZ. So being able to answer the question is based on knowing the right piece of trivia? I don't feel this is really a *puzzle* :-/

Comment: @randal'thor - I think this is just a sequence which is similar to some of the other sequences that have been posted (derived from obscure sources).

Comment: Yeah, it was just an idea I had of a set of 13 elements that most people wouldn't realize had a 14th element.